# How to solve nsf-common related error when install zsh in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, apt, zsh

Everytime I install some kind of package, at the last phase, `apt-get install` could return a **common-nfs related error**. Why the installation can't be done without this error?

[image]

[detailed pastebin here](http://pastie.org/10179691#3,17,19,22,36,38)

This question is not the same as https://serverfault.com/questions/486804/what-are-the-most-common-reasons-for-nfs-auto-mounts-to-fail

Comment: Could you please correct the spelling of nfs-common in the title of your post.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that every apt-get installation reports the problem with nfs-common is that apt-get is trying to recover from a previous problematic installation of nfs-common.  If you run "dpkg -l nfs-common", the first two characters will show a state other than 'ii' (not sure what, but an error state of some sort).

The root problem appears to be:
"/etc/init.d/statd not found"
That file is part of nfs-common, so presumably it has been deleted inadvertently (or deliberately) at some point.

If you have backups, restore that file from them.  If not, you'll need to get it from the package; you could do something like this:

`cd /tmp
mkdir nfs-common
cd nfs-common
dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/nfs-common* .
ls -l etc/init.d/statd
cp etc/init.d/statd /etc/init.d/statd`

This assumes the nfs-common deb file is still in the cache.

Once /etc/init.d/statd is back, run:

`apt-get -f install`

to get apt/dpkg to fix up the package installation.